# Where to declare variable?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make an average function. `Total` adds the values, then `Total` is divided by `n`, the number of entries.

No matter where I put `double Total;`, I get an error message. In this example I get the exception:

```
    Use of unassigned local variable 'Total'
```

If I put it before the `Average` method, both references show up as error. I'm sure it's something simple ...

```
namespace frmAssignment3
{
    class StatisticalFunctions
    {
        public static class Statistics
        {
            public static double Average(List<double> argMachineDataList)
            {
                double Total;

                int n;
                for (n = 1; n <= argMachineDataList.Count; n++) {
                    Total = argMachineDataList[n];
                }

                return Total / n;
            }

            public static double StDevSample(
                List<MachineData.MachineRecord> argMachineDataList)
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using `argMachineDataList.Average()`?  (`using System.Linq`)

Comment: @Kirk - looks like homework, which is probably why he's implementing it manually.

Comment: Do you see any problems with the for loop? What will happen when `n = argMachineDataList.Count`?

Answer (score 5):

To get rid of your issue, give `Total` a default value:

```
double Total = 0;
```

Also, you are not adding to total.  So change your `=` to `+=`:

```
Total += argMachineDataList[n];
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that there is no guarantee that the item being passed by parameter (`argMachineList`) will have a `Count` property that is greater than or equal to 1 (which is necessary for the loop to iterate AT LEAST once). If someone were to pass `new List<double>()` into this function, it would run and compile, but the for loop will never enter since the `Count` property would be 0. So it is completely possible that the for loop will never iterate once, the value of `Total` is never set, and thus you won't be able to return properly since your return statement would basically be "pointer to double / some integer n". Notice that if you were to pull `Total = argMachineList[1]` (for example) outside of the for loop, the compiler error disappears.

Everyone's simple suggestion of setting `Total`'s default value to 0 eliminates the problem; `Total` will always be able to return a value since it's value will be set regardless of whether or not the for loop iterates once.

```
    public static double Average(List<double> argMachineList)
    {
        double Total = 0.0;
        int n;
        for (n = 0; n < argMachineList.Count; n++)
        {
            Total += argMachineList[n];
        }
        return Total / argMachineList.Count;
    }
```

Comment: - 1 I don't know why this answer is getting upvotes, this will throw an exception on any valid input since you will try to access `argMachineList[argMachineList.Count]`

Comment: @BrokenGlass  It was a mistake from copying/editing his original; I've fixed it. I would hope the votes were more about explaining the logic than harping on a small error of editing.

Comment: Now your average calculation is wrong because of your correction

Answer (score 1):

Just do this and you'll be fine:

```
    public static double Average(List<double> argMachineDataList)
    {
        double Total = 0.0;

        int n;
        for (n = 0; n < argMachineDataList.Count; n++)
        {
            Total += argMachineDataList[n]; // added += since you probably want to sum value
        }

        return Total / n;
    }
```

I also added a `+=` between Total and your argMachineDataList[n] as since you want the total you need to actually sum up the values.

Comment: Why does setting `Total = 0.0` help?

Comment: @Tester101 the error says that Total is unassigned, so the fix is to assign it a value. Since you are summing up, it makes sense that you use 0 as it has no impact on anything. If you think about it, before you assign it a value it has no value. What is "no value" + any number? Undefined since "no value" isn't a number. That is why you need to initialize it to something.

Comment: What about the for loop, what happens when `n = argMachineDataList.Count`?

Comment: Member variables are always initialized to a default value corresponding to their type (`0`, `null`, etc.) unless an explicit initialization expression specifies another value. However, local variables are NOT automatically initialized. `Total` will remain undefined until you assign it a value!

Comment: @Tester101 I fixed the code I copied from you (should've payed attention in the first place). The problem with what you originally had is that Lists are zero based so you would go out of range when `n = argMachineDataList.Count` To fix that you make `n = 0` and then `n < argMachineDataList.Count`

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize Total:

```
double Total = 0;
```

or as said *@Kirk Woll* use **linq**:

```
double Total = argMachineDataList.Average();
```

to avoid to write:

```
for (int n = 0; n < argMachineDataList.Count; n++)
//the first index of the list start from 0 and the last one is n-1 so      
//argMachineDataList.Count-1 so you need < not <=
{               
     Total += argMachineDataList[n]; 
     //Remember that if you want to 
     //increment total you need the += instead of =
}

return Total / argMachineDataList.Count;
//Then remeber that n int this case is a local variable so you can't use it out 
//of the for loop
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize total

```
double total = 0.0;
```

You're also starting with the 2nd element instead of the first by setting n = 1 in the for loop.

Comment: Arg! yeah... Thanks!... I think my teacher wants a function to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the issue...

```
double Total = 0;
```

The thing is, what you are trying to do, is using a variable that has not been assigned a value yet. Before you use a variable, you *must* assign it a value.

What you originally had, `double Total;` is *declaring*  the variable, not *assigning* it.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop may only run once, leaving `Total` unassinged. Init Total when you declare it.

```
double Total = 0.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several bugs in your code, one that hasn't been mentioned yet is an "off by one" bug in your `for` loop - the first element you are adding has an index of 1, but the first item in the collection has an index of zero:

```
double total = 0;
for (int n = 0; n < argMachineDataList.Count; n++)
{
    total += argMachineDataList[n];
}

return total / argMachineDataList.Count; // will throw exception if n = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double Average(List<double> argMachineDataList)
{
    //First lets handle the case where argMachineDataList is empty.
    // Otherwise we'll return Double.NaN when we divide by zero.
    if(argMachineDataList.Count == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("argMachineDataList cannot be an empty List.");
    }

    //Second we have to assign an initial value to Total, 
    // because there is no guarantee it will be set in the loop. 
    //And since it's a local variable, it will not automatically be set.
    double Total = 0.0;

    //Next since Lists are Zero Base indexed, 
    // we'll want to start with n = 0 so we include the first element.
    //We also want the loop to stop before n = argMachineDataList.Count, 
    // or we'll get an ArgumentOutOfRange Exception when trying to access 
    //  argMachineDataList[n] (when n = argMachineDataList.Count).
    for (int n = 0; n < argMachineDataList.Count; n++)
    {
        //Since we want to add the value of argMachineDataList[n] to Total, 
        // we have to change from = to += 
        //   (which is the same as saying Total = Total + argMachineDataList[n]).
        Total += argMachineDataList[n];
    }
    //Lastly, n will be out of scope outside of the for loop. 
    // So we'll use argMachineDataList.Count, to get the number of items.
    return Total / argMachineDataList.Count;
}
```